# Received an internal error when trying to delete a document in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cron call which simply deletes a document like so:

```
// expiringBoardPostCronCall
// This function is called to remove all board posts at the nearest expire time
exports.expiringBoardPostCronCall = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  // Get the current date rounded to nearest 15 minutes, divide by 1000 to convert from ms to s
  const currentTime = Date.now();
  const coeff = 1000 * 60 * 5;
  const roundedTime = ((Math.round(currentTime / coeff)) * coeff) / 1000;
  // Delete the expiring document
  db.collection('expireTimes').doc(roundedTime.toString()).delete().then(snapshot => {
    // Do nothing, the expiring document was removed successfully
    response.end()
    return
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error("Error removing expireTimes document: ", error);
    response.end()
  });
})
```

I recently received the following error from function logs:

> Error: 13 INTERNAL: Received RST_STREAM with code 2
>
> at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26)
>
> at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:175:52)
>
> at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:341:141)
>
> at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:304:181)
>
> at Http2CallStream.outputStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:116:74)
>
> at Http2CallStream.maybeOutputStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:155:22)
>
> at Http2CallStream.endCall (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:141:18)
>
> at ClientHttp2Stream.stream.on (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:403:22)
>
> at ClientHttp2Stream.emit (events.js:198:13)
>
> at ClientHttp2Stream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:466:23)
>
> code: 13,
>
> details: 'Received RST_STREAM with code 2',
>
> metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} } }
>
> Function execution took 21 ms, finished with status code: 200

I have been following the github threads listed [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/1023) and [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/issues/679) but there does not appear to be a good answer. It seems other people are having the same issue with nearly identical error logs. I am running in Node.js 10. Has anyone else seen this or had a similar issue? Any solutions?

Comment: Do you use the latest version of the dependencies?

Comment: Hi @SanzioAngeli indeed this is very weird. However, since this seems to be an issue with the Node.js API, I believe the best is to follow the threads on Github, due to the fact that the API are supported directly by the developers.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have not checked in a couple weeks so I will take another look and get back to you.

Comment: @gso_gabriel Thank you for the advice. I will continue to follow the github thread but figured I would see if anyone knew the answer here

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Only the firebase-admin dependency needed to be updated. firebase-functions was up to date. I will redeploy and let everyone know if I get the issue again. Also worth noting this was an isolated issue that I have only observed once.

Comment: After rolling back to Node.js 8 environment, I have not seen the problem since